# Probability Vectors

Tags: discrete-mathematics, markov-chains

We need to find the probability vector of:

```
[ 2/3  1/3  0   ]
[ 1/4  1/2  1/4 ]
[ 0    4/5  1/5 ]
```

m1 + m2 + m3 = 1

m1 = (2/3)(m1) + (1/4)(m2) + (0)(m3) = (2/3)(m1) + (1/4)(m2)
m2 = (1/3)(m1) + (1/2)(m2) + (4/5)(m3) 
m3 = 0)(m1) + (1/4)(m2) + (1/5)(m3) = (1/4)(m2) + (1/5)(m3)

This is where I get stuck, I'm confused how to solve for m1, m2, and m3.

I keep getting the wrong answer.

The right answer is: 4/11, 16/33, and 5/33

Comment: [Here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a tutorial on how to use MathJax formatting to make your questions a little easier to read :)

Answer (score 0):

We need to find an eigenvector the sum of whose components is $1$ to the matrix 
$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac23&\frac13&0\\
\frac14&\frac12&\frac14\\
0&\frac45&\frac15.\end{bmatrix}^T$$
belonging to its eigen-vector $1$.
Such a vector is

$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac4{11}\\
\frac{16}{33}\\
\frac5{33}\end{bmatrix}.$$

It is easy to check that $$\begin{bmatrix}\frac23&\frac14&0\\
\frac13&\frac12&\frac45\\
0&\frac14&\frac15.\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\frac4{11}\\
\frac{16}{33}\\
\frac5{33}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac4{11}\\
\frac{16}{33}\\
\frac5{33}\end{bmatrix}.$$